# How to use library org.hibernate in java?

Tags: hibernate, netbeans

I create new project in Netbeans, but when I look the library it still using JDK 1.6 (default) I want to change into JDK 6 Update 10 but how? I already instal JDK 6 Update 10 but when I import org.hibernate the neatbeans didn't know which library that org.hibernate.

someone can help me? THX

Comment: There's no such thing as JDK 1.10. JDK 1.6 (aka Java 6) is the most recent version. You claim you've installed JDK 1.10 - what do you actually mean?

Comment: (JDK) 6 Update 10 i mean, ahaha

Comment: What particular feature of update 10 do you care about so much, out of interest? It strikes me as very unlikely that the JDK version has anything to do with your Hibernate issue.

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans you can define a new Java Platform from Tools > Java Platforms. This brings up the platform manager. At this point you can click the "Add Platform" button and browse to the location of the new platform. You will then have multiple platforms set up and you can configure each project to use the appropriate platform.

To add the hibernate library you can go to Tools > libraries and click "New Library". Then browse to the location of the Hibernate jar files.

Each project can then have th enew library added by right-clicking on the libraries link in the project browser and clicking "Add Library".

Answer (score 0):

JDK 1.6 is the current released version.

I really hope you aren't talking about Java 10 there.

And even worse would be if you wanted to use Java 1.1! Which was out over 10 years ago.